# Can I prevent the Google Photos photo viewer from showing the Share button?

Tags: android, photo

I followed the ["Taking Photos Simply"](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) page on the Android developer site and using their sample code the photo gets saved to a path like:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20160427_170609_-607831068.jpg
```

I then want to view the photo, so I use a view intent which starts a photo viewer activity,which on my phone provided by Google Photos:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + mCurrentPhotoPath), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

On this photo viewer activity there is a Share button, but if I try to share to another app from there the receiving app is unable to read the file.

I don't want the photo to be shared from the viewer activity anyway, so is there any way for me to hint to the viewer activity that the photo should not be shareable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so is there any way for me to hint to the viewer activity that the photo should not be shareable?

No, sorry.

If you save the image to internal storage, then use `FileProvider` or similar approaches to serve up the image, you can ensure that a third-party app cannot directly hand your `Uri` over to another app. However:

- Buggy image viewers might offer up a share option anyway, even though it is doomed to fail
- Nothing is stopping the image viewer from making its own copy of the image, then sharing that